# App Termination between UITest slow

Tags: ios, xcode, uitest, xcuitest

We currently face the problem that our UITest's take to long.

The reason is that the termination of the App from the last UITest takes between 20 and 50 seconds. With the 90 UITest we currently have this amounts to 90min for one test round (which currently fails on our CI because of a 90 min limit).

Here a small output of the Test steps.

```
2018-05-18 11:15:34.757243+0200 OurAppUITests-Runner[46090:16633867] Currently executing: "Given the app is launched"
t =     0.21s Given the app is launched
t =     0.21s     Open de.ourApp.ourApp
t =     0.26s         Launch de.ourApp.ourApp
t =     0.26s             Terminate de.ourApp.ourApp:46132
t =    32.21s             Wait for de.ourApp.ourApp to idle
```

We tried terminating the app at the end of every UITest, but it just moved the "waiting" time to the end of the UITest.

We are using [Cucumberish](https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/Cucumberish) to generate the test out of gherkin files. But we run the Tests using XCUITests.

I would be thankful for every reason that can cause the termination to take this long.

Answer (score 0):

A Git Bisect showed us that the Problem started when the Thread Sanitizer was enabled for the Test Target.
Disabling it fixed the Problem.

I will probably start a new Question or/and open a Radar about this, because this Problem didn't occur when the test where run in Xcode. Only with xcodebuild (fastlane) they surfaced.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the exact answer to your question but an alternate approach which would solve your time limit problem.

You could use parallelization, which would run feature files in 3 different simulators at once. To do this you will need to edit your test target scheme. In scheme edit menu select Build tab and check the box for Parallelize Build.

Try testing it now, the termination will still take time but it will be at least terminating 3 tests now instead of one.